# Write multiple values into a single csv cell using PHP loops and arrays

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I'm trying to write multiple values into a single csv cell using PHP loops and arrays.

```
<?php

$data = array
(
3 => array
    (
        'name' => 'Mars',
        'type' => 'Terrestrial Planet',
        'diameter' => 0.532,
        'mass' => 0.11,
        'rings' => 0,
        'position' => 4,
        'gases' => array
            (
                0 => 'CO2',
                1 => 'N2',
                2 => 'Ar'
            ),

        'satellites' => array
            (
                0 => array
                    (
                        'name' => 'Phobos',
                        'radius' => 6.20
                    ),

                1 => array
                    (
                        'name' => 'Deimos',
                        'radius' => 6.20
                    )

            )

    )

);

function writeCSV($array){

$str = [];
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp,  array('Name','Type','Diameter','Mass','Rings','Position','Gases','Satellite-Name','Satellite-Radius'),"\t");

foreach ($array as &$fields) {

   $str[] = $fields['name'];
   $str[] = $fields['type'];
   $str[] = $fields['diameter'];
   $str[] = $fields['mass'];
   $str[] = $fields['rings'];
   $str[] = $fields['position'];

   if(is_array($fields['gases'])){
        foreach ($fields['gases'] as $gas)
            array_push($str, $gas);
   }

   if(is_array($fields['satellites'])){ 

        foreach ($fields['satellites'] as $satellite)
            $str[] = $satellite['name'];

        foreach ($fields['satellites'] as $satellite)
            $str[] = $satellite['radius'];

   }

  fputcsv($fp, $str);
  $str = [];

}


}

writeCSV($data);

?>
```

The outcome of this writes:

```
Name    Type    Diameter    Mass    Rings   Position    Gases   Satellite-Name  Satellite-Radius
Mercury,"Terrestrial Planet",0.382,0.06,0,1
Venus,"Terrestrial Planet",0.949,0.82,0,2,CO2,N2
Earth,"Terrestrial Planet",1,1,0,3,N2,O2,Ar,Moon,1737.1
Mars,"Terrestrial Planet",0.532,0.11,0,4,CO2,N2,Ar,Phobos,Deimos,6.2,6.2
```

to the file. I really need it to write multiple (Gases, Satellite-Name  Satellite-Radius) values into a single cell seperated by a space and wrapped in quotes say, i.e.

```
Name    Type    Diameter    Mass    Rings   Position    Gases   Satellite-Name  Satellite-Radius
Mercury,"Terrestrial Planet",0.382,0.06,0,1
Venus,"Terrestrial Planet",0.949,0.82,0,2,"CO2 N2"
Earth,"Terrestrial Planet",1,1,0,3,"N2 O2 Ar",Moon,1737.1
Mars,"Terrestrial Planet",0.532,0.11,0,4,"CO2 N2 Ar","Phobos Deimos","6.2 6.2"
```

I guess this would occur by intercepting the satellites and gases loops somehow but am struggling to concatenate or augment the gases and satellite loops to get the data into one array cell value.

Comment: First append the gases and satellites into a single string, then push them to the stack, i.e. these entries need to be in a single index (see the fputcsv documentation why your current implementation goes wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gases are easy, instead of

```
foreach ($fields['gases'] as $gas)
            array_push($str, $gas);
```

use

```
$str[] = join(' ', $fields['gases']);
```

For the names and radii the simplest solution is probably [array_column](http://docs.php.net/array_column), as long as `(PHP 5 >= 5.5.0)` isn't a problem....

```
$str[] = join(' ', array_column($fields['satellites'], 'name'));
$str[] = join(' ', array_column($fields['satellites'], 'radius'));
```

but if any of these values may contain whitespaces (e.g. Jupiter's moon `S/2000 J 11`) you have to encode that first.